Are "French residents" and "the French population" synonymous with "people in France"?

Around 200 million pounds (fake data*) was invested in perfume by French residents/the French population in 2010.

I wonder if French residents or the French population can be interpreted as people in France, which is what they are supposed to refer to, in this sentence.

What if  I said: Around 200 million pounds were invested in rice by Chinese residents. Chinese or Japanese or some other Asian country. See how weird that is? What exactly do you want to know? How much is spent on x by residents, population or people from some country?

By people from some country it is.

I guess the weird part you're talking about is the use of the word "invested"?

When referring to consumer spending in a specific country, in this case France, it is advisable to avoid the expressions French residents, the French population or citizens, as that would exclude immigrants, non-resident citizens, and also tourists from the equation. These people may be living abroad, working in France or only visiting it but the money they spend on products in France is every bit as important as the French people who work and live in France.
We can refer to a country's expenditure.

In 2010, about £200 million was spent on perfume in France


I understand. To my recollection, you are one of the few members of the forum who know how much IELTS examiners care about paraphrasing. So, my problem is, if I follow the definition of the term "people in France" strictly, I don't know many alternatives to it. "France's expenditure" also seems to be useful here, but it isn't enough because I have to make comments on a lot of data in one essay. So, could you please provide some other alternatives to the two phrases?

"French people", "the French" and "Frenchmen / Frenchwomen" have the same meaning, the last one I feel is slightly old fashioned.

@KenAdams Be careful, in France the currency is "euro" = € , not pounds = £ Maybe the original text uses the first symbol and you misunderstood for pounds.

Thank you! But don't "French people" and "the French" equal "French citizens"?

Yes, more or less. It's unlikely  you would talk about products being bought/consumed by "French citizens" though. I'd say "French people"/ "the French"  would be more common. Look up some phrases on Google.

I noticed that you added "the French population" to the list of words which should be avoided. Is that because of the same reason James gave?

For the reasons I also stated. If I'm in France, as a tourist, as an immigrant, as an itinerant worker and I buy an expensive bottle of perfume, where does my money go? In France, the UK or in Italy?

The thing is, I don't understand the difference between "the French population" and "the French" or "French people". If the French population equals French citizens, then yes, you have already explained it. But I'm not sure if the French population is unsuitable for the same reason as French citizens, or for a different reason. I don't know the exact definition of the phrase.

What I've gathered so far: The French/French people is okay. French citizens and French residents exclude a group of people who should be considered, so not okay. But what is the definition of "the French population"? To my mind, it means the same as "the French" or "French people". But according to your answer, it seems to mean the same as "French residents/citizens"?

You're now wondering what is the difference between French population, the French and the French people. That is a different question. You can look these terms up in dictionaries and you might come to the conclusion there is no  significant difference. Do you think a  Thai person living in Viet Nam is included in "Viet Nam population"? Maybe.   My answer  recommends saying ...million was spent in France and also  In 2023 France spent... Try Googling phrases with the verbs "spent" and "consumed" e.g "The French population consumed" and see whether the number of hits change.

The French population suggests the people born and currently  living  in France. As an Italian if I lived and worked  in Marseilles for ten years I doubt anyone would give me French citizenship and  a passport. If I had married a Frenchman and had children with him I could become a Fr. citizen but would the French identify me as a compatriot? Some might but some will not.

Yes, "People in France" would have a similar meaning
Of course, some people in France are not resident there, and some French people don't live in France.
It is unlikely that the "population" invested in perfume - this sounds like something that everybody did, or was organised in some way.  I'm also not sure about the word "invest", which suggests that they hope to make a profit in some way.

Yes, I meant "in France". It was a silly mistake. Regarding your answer to the second phrase, I guess you meant to write "this doesn't sound like..."? I think when we write, "Around 200 million pounds was spent on perfume by people in France," readers won't assume that all people in France played a part in making that amount, either. So does it really have to be something every or most French people do for us to say "the French population do it"?

If you say "the population do it" it sounds like an organised and universal action.  Something done as a group, not individually. "The population of the town evacuated because of the volcano"
